# Custom cell label text color

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel, textcolor

I  want to change UILabel text color in initWithStyle method of UITableViewCell. But color is not getting changed.
But when color changing is done in cellForRowAtIndexPath method,color is getting changed. Why?

Comment: Can you please put code you have written in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: And the code in initwithStyle please. And also tell us if you are using storyboards and prototype cells or not.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you are using your label you just need to set textColor property:

For creating tableViewCell in `- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView` method I think you have used like following:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

there may be possibility that you have your style is either `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` or `UITableViewCellStyleValue1 or`UITableViewCellStyleValue2`or`UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`.

Now whatever style you are using if you are adding your own label than use:

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,25)];
lbl.text = @"your Text";
[lbl setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

and if you are not adding your own labels and using default label which is `textLabel` or `detailTextLabel` of `UITableViewCell` object:

```
[cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

If you are adding any label in subview like:

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,25)];
lbl.text = @"your Text";
[lbl setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

you can replace `greenColor` with your desire color.
Hope this helps :)